# How to add elements to WordPress appearance->menu admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I would like to add a custom post Type Archive page to my menu, using the appearance->menu admin.

I found several blog posts (although a bit old) proposing different solutions, but I didn't managed to make it work.

The key problem seems find the correct filter or action to add elements to that menu without rewriting completely.

For example : http://codeseekah.com/2012/03/01/custom-post-type-archives-in-wordpress-menus-2/
this solution doesn't seem to work because it call `add_meta_box` with a `"nav-menus"` post type, which I can't found no documentation about.

Any clue ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: This is unfortunately still not (fully) possible. [See this trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16075) saga on the subject. Hopefully this will make it into core soon.

Comment: The discussion in this ticket is very interesting as it point something that always missed me in Wordpress : the ability to easily display lists of page anywhere, to reflect the original folder-file structuration of internet. In my opinion, but I may be wrong, this is the last point where Wordpress suffer from his "blog spirit" inheritance.